# Como usar hammerjs con angular 17

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angularjs

quiero usar el gesto de swipe de la libreria hammer para hacer un carrusel en angular 17, y para eso tengo que usar la clase Hammer pero no me la reconoce y me da error..

lo que hice fue instalar hammer en las dependencias:

```
npm i --save hammerjs
```

y luego en el componente en la parte de imports

```
@Component({
  selector: 'banner-hero',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ButtonComponent, HammerModule],
  templateUrl: './banner-hero.component.html',
  styleUrl: './banner-hero.component.css'
})
```

y ahí en el mismo archivo del componente quiero usar el Hammer pero no me deja

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const hammer = new Hammer();
  }
```

**EDIT:**

el error esta en la sentencia new Hammer(), dice: `Cannot find name 'Hammer'. Did you mean 'hammer'?ts(2552)`

typscript del componente:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MoviesService } from '../../services/movies.service';
import { Pelicula, Peliculas } from '../../models/peliculas.model';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ButtonComponent } from '../button/button.component';
import { HammerModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import 'hammerjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'banner-hero',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ButtonComponent, HammerModule],
  templateUrl: './banner-hero.component.html',
  styleUrl: './banner-hero.component.css'
})
export class BannerHeroComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChild('banner-hero') container: ElementRef|undefined;

  data: {loading: boolean, peliculas: Pelicula[]} = {loading: false, peliculas: []};
  actualIndex: number = 0;
  

  imgPath = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/';
  imgHdPath = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/';

  actualImg = '';

  constructor(private moviesService: MoviesService){}


  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const hammer = new Hammer();
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data = {loading: false, peliculas: []}
    this.moviesService.getListaMedia('movie', 'popular').subscribe(data=>{
      this.data = {loading: false, peliculas: data.results.slice(0,5)};
      this.actualImg = `${this.imgPath}${this.data.peliculas[this.actualIndex].backdrop_path}`;
      console.log(data);
      console.log(this.data);
    });

    

  }


  moverBanner(sumar: boolean, mov: number){
    if (mov ==1 || mov == -1){
      if(sumar)
        this.actualIndex = this.actualIndex + mov;
      else
        this.actualIndex = mov;
      this.actualImg = `${this.imgPath}${this.data.peliculas[this.actualIndex].backdrop_path}`;
    }
  }


  isNew(date: string):boolean{
    let prevDate: Date = new Date(date);
    let currentDate: Date = new Date();

    let timeDiference = currentDate.getTime() - prevDate.getTime();
    const timeInMonth:number = 1000*60*60*24*30;

    

    return timeDiference <= timeInMonth;
  }


}
```

Comment: ¿Has importado la librería en el componente?

Comment: Si lo he importado

Comment: edita la pregunta y agrega los detalles.

Comment: Ahi lo edite y agregue lo del componente